# Find a function for my P&P RPG's skill calculation

Tags: functions

I'm (software engineer;) writing a computer program for a pen and paper RPG; We use a simple iterative procedure to get the actual skill level. I have been trying to create a continuous function which will come close to the same values. I will try and explain the procedure as well as I can:

- skill level (lvl)
- statistic (stat)
- experience points (xp)

when you begin your lvl will equal your stat, while your xp > 0
while lvl < stat * 2
1 xp => lvl + 3
xp => xp - 1

while lvl < stat * 3
1 xp => lvl + 2
xp => xp - 1

while lvl < stat * 4
1 xp => lvl + 1
xp => xp - 1

etc, etc

quick list:
1xp = +3 lvl
1xp = +2 lvl
1xp = +1 lvl
1xp = +2/3 lvl
1xp = +1/2 lvl

As an example:
stat 60, 20 xp => lvl 120
stat 30, 20 xp => lvl 80
stat 60, 60 xp => lvl 190
stat 73, 20 xp => lvl 133

Could someone help me find a function which will calculate the right skill level given some xp and a statistic?

EDIT: Here is a link to a little JSFiddle which will calculate the correct level given a statistic and some xp. As you can see it's done with an itteration; I hope this fiddle helps.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nwkr92e/)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi! Since you're a software engineer, please use the proper markup to format your questions. This way indeed it's really easier to understand at best!

Comment: Also, please add more words to explain what is going on.  There are "=" and "=>" symbols all over the place, and they seem to mean different things in different places.  Also, what is $x$?

Comment: HI, thank you for the reaction. @MattAllegro, could you tell me more about which parts are improperly formatted? I might have used a code format but my psuedo-code is more descriptive then actual code. If you give me a bit more to work with I'll reformat the question.

Comment: @vadim123 I use the = to test for equality and => to 'assign to' or 'then'. I will edit the rest of my answer because you are correct. I misstyped and x should be xp, thank you. I will also try and get a better graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your posted code, here is some pseudocode that does what you want without a loop.

$stat_a=ceil(stat/3)$
$stat_b=stat_a+ceil(stat/2)$
$stat_c=stat_b+ceil(stat)$
$stat_d=stat_c+ceil(stat*3/2)$

$value=stat+max(0,(1/2)*(xp-stat_d))+$
$+max(0,(2/3)*(min(xp,stat_d)-stat_c))+$
$+max(0,(1)*(min(xp,stat_c)-stat_b))+$
$+max(0,(2)*(min(xp,stat_b)-stat_a))+$
$+max(0,(3)*(min(xp,stat_a))$

Your question as posted doesn't make sense, and doesn't match your pseudocode (even after your revision of x to xp).  In the future, I suggest you proofread your questions more carefully.

Comment: I apologize if the question didn't make sense. I will try and formulate them better in the future.